# How to stop current branch of actions but not terminate the whole flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have 4 streams of actions which filter out selections: 
1-10k
11-30k 
30-99k 
100k+

On my previous question I wanted to avoid heavily nesting items, that has been achieved. Now, I am faced with the problem where, I have 3 Streams that are FALSE and one is TRUE but I don't want to Terminate the whole flow just because they are false.

So, I have a workaround of "Do Until" which will run infinitely, until the flow is forced to terminate.

I was wondering, are there any other methods that are recommended?

Another I can think of is Sending an Email asking for a response which never gets answered. Neither are ideal solutions, but suffice. Are there official ways of performing this? Something like, end this "line of inquiry" if condition is false?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to just set some variables instead of infinite loops to stop the flow.

By setting Variables you are on top able to configure special behavior given a special constellation of variables.

If you wont need them its at least way faster than a infinite loop till the flow breaks up.